# Object has no attribute get in serializer

Tags: python, django

I created a serializer and an API endpoint so I can retrieve some data from a Django DB in my React app but getting this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'ProgrammingChallengesView' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Here is my models.py:

```
#creating programming challenges
class ProgrammingChallenges(models.Model):
    challenge_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    challenge_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    challenge_description = models.TextField()
    challenge_expectations = models.TextField()
```

my serializer:

```
from accounts.models import ProgrammingChallenges
...
class ProgrammingChallengesView(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProgrammingChallenges
        fields = '__all__'
```

and my urls.py:

```
path('api/programming_challenges/', ProgrammingChallengesView, name='programming_challenges'),
```

Comment: You need at least change your code in urls.py to: ProgrammingChallengesView.as_view()

Comment: @var211 I get the error `AttributeError: type object 'ProgrammingChallengesSerializer' has no attribute 'as_view'` when I do that

Comment: A `ModelSerializer` is not a view...

Comment: I see, so as Willem Van Onsem made a point, you need to write a **view function**. And use your serializer inside that view function. Then you need to put this view inside a path, in urls.py.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments; I clearly didn't understand that a serializer only transforms my data to make it available through an API. I still had to create a view for my API's endpoint.

I opted to create a `ReadOnlyModelView` because I only want to `GET` data from this endpoint.

Here is what I wrote in my views:

```
class ProgrammingChallengesView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProgrammingChallengesSerializer
    queryset = ProgrammingChallenges.objects.all()

    @action(detail=False)
    def get_list(self, request):
        pass
```

and in my urls.py:

```
path('api/programming_challenges/', ProgrammingChallengesView.as_view({'get':'list'}), name='programming_challenges'),
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use serializers as views.

Code shoudld be:

models.py

```
class ProgrammingChallenge(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    expectations = models.TextField()
```

Some advices:

1. Your model name could be ProgrammingChallenge(singular) instead of ProgrammingChallenges(plural).
2. I don't think it's necessary to add prefix challenge before all field names. Because it's clear that that the fields are in a Model called ProgrammingChallenge. And it would be more readable and easier to access them like **ProgrammingChallenge.name** than **ProgrammingChallenge.challenge_name**
3. It's not necessary to add field **id** manually. Django model automatically adds **id** field as primary_key

serializer.py

```
from accounts.models import ProgrammingChallenge
...
class ProgrammingChallengeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProgrammingChallenge
        fields = '__all__'
```

No problem in serializers.

Now, main problem is you don't have any view in your code. You can use [APIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/), [generic views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) or [viewset](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/). In this example i'm going to use ModelViewSet that handles CRUD operations for specified model.

viewsets.py

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

from .models import ProgrammingChallenge
from .serializers import ProgrammingChallengSerializer


class ProgrammingChallengViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ProgrammingChallenge.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProgrammingChallengeSerializer
```

urls.py

```
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter

from .viewsets import ProgrammingChallenge

router = SimpleRouter()
router.register('challengr', ProgrammingChallengeViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Another advantage of using viewset, it also generate all endpoints for its CRUD methods automatically via routes.

It should help you to start your first project.

Comment: Try to be more encouraging :)